# Generic - the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Placement<T>
        where T : IElement
{ }
```

and I have another class that inherits from it:

```
public class ResourcePlacement : Placement<Resource>
{ }
```

Somewhere I have business logic that saves the placement to the database:

```
public interface IPlacementManagement<T, TPlacement>
        where T : IElement
        where TPlacement : Placement<T>
{     
        void SavePlacement(TPlacement placement);
}

abstract class PlacementManagementImplBase<T, TPlacement> : IPlacementManagement<T, TPlacement>
        where T : IElement
        where TPlacement : Placement<T>
{
    public virtual void SavePlacement(TPlacement placement)
    {
        // Implementation.
    }
}
```

On the client side, I am trying to save it like this:

```
var placement = new ResourcePlacement();
// Do something with placement.
this.placementMangagement.SavePlacement(placement);
```

However I got the following error:

`the best overloaded method match for IPlacementManagement<TEntity, TPlacement>.SavePlacement(TPlacement) has some invalid arguments.`

Why do I have this error?
How can I pass `ResourcePlacement` instance as parameter in `SavePlacement` method?

Comment: Well what is the type of `this.placementMangagement`? (It would be easier to help you if we had a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.)

Comment: But we can infer can't we? Seems to me that this.placementManagment is of type IPlacementManagement<TEntity, TPlacement>, probably where TPlacement is of type Placement<TEntity>. However, the SavePlacement method receives an instance of ResourcePlacement, which is Placement<Resource>. But Placement<Resource> != Placement<TEntity>, since we don't know anything about who or what is TEntity.